# how to stop progress indicator after downloading a pdf

Tags: jquery

There is a link on my page to a pdf file.  Clicking on the link takes a really long time, so I'd like to throw up a progress indicator gif showing that it is something that takes a while.  But how do you hide the indicator once the pdf has been generated on the server side and finished downloading?  (basically your browser now says you are opening a pdf file and asks you what to do)

at this point is there an event that fires or anything I can poll to check to hide the progress indicator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript does not have access to information on what's being downloaded. The only thing you can do is load the PDF in a Iframe and hook up the onload event on the Iframe. Even then the event will fire when the PDF starts loading, not when it is complete.

**EDIT**: [kalendae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207204/kalendae) has alternate answer.

If you have server-side access you can set a cookie with the response and poll for its value on the client.

See: http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx

Comment: just tried it and it does not work.  loading a new page in an iframe will trigger the load callback but loading a pdf into the iframe does not result in a onload event on the iframe.  is there some other event that will get fired?

Comment: i accepted this answer since it was the only one, but the solution does not actually work. instead i used the solution on this site: http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx

Comment: Wow, that's very clever. I never thought of a server-side work-around like that.