# How to get readyState from GWT Frame object?

Tags: gwt, iframe, frame

I'm using GWT 2.3.0 in my project and I have an iframe and a loading mask. When the iframe content (to be more specific, the content is a PDF) is loaded I need to hide the loading mask.

I tried using:

```
Frame frame = new Frame("https://www.example.com.br/example.pdf") {{
   addDomHandler(new LoadHandler() {
      public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
         loadingMask.setVisible(false);
      }
   }, LoadEvent.getType());
}};
```

Because of the content is a PDF, it does not work in IE.

Is there a way to get the readyState iframe property with GWT?

I would appreciate any feedback. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to get the readyState GWT Frame property:

```
frame.getElement().getAttribute("readyState")
```

Answer (score -1):

Just override the `onLoad()` method on `Frame`:

```
Frame frame = new Frame("https://www.example.com.br/example.pdf") {
    @Override
    protected void onLoad() {
        super.onLoad();
        loadingMask.setVisible(false);
    }
};
```

Comment: If I try to load a common web page, e.g. www.google.com it works, but it doesn't work loading a PDF

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465115/how-to-stop-progress-indicator-after-downloading-a-pdf

Comment: It's not true. Onload is called after widget is attached, not after loading a frame contents.